# How to get auth token from google sign in?

Tags: android, android-studio, oauth-2.0, googlesigninaccount

I'm trying to figure out how to get the auth token for the admin sdk from the google sign in on android.

I can use google sign in to get the account information, and I can get the phone to request permission. Whenever I try to get information it says that the request did not have the authorization required.

After asking for a permission with:

```
GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(activity, requestCode, account, *scopes)
```

And getting the account back in the onActivityResult method:

```
account = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data).getResult(ApiException::class.java)
```

So I'm pretty sure I need to get an auth token, but I am not sure how to get it?

Answer (score 0):

When you configure Google Sign-In you need to call the [requestIdToken](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInOptions.Builder#requestIdToken(java.lang.String)) method and pass it your server's web client ID. Your backend server can then use this token to authenticate.

The `Task<GoogleSignInAccount>` result should contain a `GoogleSignInAccount` object, which has a `getIdToken()` method that you can send to your backend server:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up figuring this out by using a library called appauth. It allows you to log in and get the access token for oauth servers.